# Table of Contents in LaTeX

Tags: table-of-contents

I wanna add some of the headings like Acknowledgments, Abstract, etc. in TOC. The problem I'm having is that, when I give the command of \tableofcontents, the heading following the command show up but the above mentioned heading which are above the command of \tableofcontents do not show up. How can I fix this?

Also by giving the command of \tableofcontents, a heading of CONTENTS also comes in TOC. Is this possible to avoid the head "Contents" in TOC? Like can I give the heading of contents on my own?

Comment: Welcome to tex.se... Can you provide your `MWE`?

Comment: MWE (Minimal Working Example), is a small but complete document beginning with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`. Knowing your document preamble will help us to help you.

Comment: I'm guessing that you are using the `memoir` class. Try `\tableofcontents*` instead of the unstarred version.